# How are @wire apexMethodParams in JS mapped to Apex function parameters and types?

Tags: apex, javascript, lwc-wire-adapter

When writing a Lightning Web Component, you can use `@wire` to call an Apex function. `@wire` can, optionally, take an object (referred to as `apexMethodParams`) whose properties will be mapped to arguments in the called Apex function.

This is documented here:
[Wire Apex Methods to Lightning Web Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.apex_wire_method).

There are also examples in [lwc-recipes](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes).

How are the properties and types in the Javascript `apexMethodParams` object mapped to arguments and types in Apex? Is there a reference document on the "rules"? From what I can tell, some type coercion appears to be supported. (ex: Using a number-as-string in Javascript for an Apex function that takes an Integer.)

The syntax of `'$_var_name_'` seems to require that the property be a string.

Attempting to do something like: `@wire(myFunction, { count: this.count })`

Resulted in errors being thrown because `this` was undefined at the time it was used.

But doing: `@wire(myFunction, {count : '$count'})`

Seemed to work fine and `count` appeared to be automatically converted to an `Integer` for use in the following Apex method:

```
public with sharing class MyClass {
  @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
  public static List<Account> myFunction(Integer count) {
  }
}
```

Curious where this is documented and if there's an official reference document on the rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reactive properties, using `'$varname'`, are not the same as Template literals, which are in the form of `` `${varname}` ``. This is not a string interpolation, but rather a specific convention of `@wire` that causes every reactive property to be examined every time a render cycle is triggered to see if any properties have changed.

Wire methods call a method named `stableJSONStringify`, which is an implementation loosely based on [epoberezkin/fast-json-stable-stringify](https://github.com/epoberezkin/fast-json-stable-stringify), according to comments in the source. This is basically `JSON.stringify`, except that the keys are sorted in lexicographical order. This data is directly sent to the server without any knowledge of the data types of the parameters.

This means that `'$varname'` in the reactive sense, can be any type of serializable data. For example, Apex has no problem coercing a JavaScript Object into an Apex Map. It can also convert a JavaScript Array to a Set or List, as long as all the elements conform to the specialization (data type) of that Set or List.

For its part, wire will only trigger when it detects changes between the last value of `stableJSONStringify` and the new one. Some types of updates could theoretically go unnoticed (e.g. replacing one object with another, but having the same internal values).

Apex is responsible for attempting to coerce the data types for the parameters. Since JSON only supports Number, String, Boolean, Array, Object, and null, Apex has to interpret these values to the various types of parameters you can use. The "rules" appear to be unwritten, though.

From what I can tell, Salesforce can coerce the value from JavaScript if, and only if, `JSON.deserialize` or `.valueOf` would not return an error. For example, a `Date` in JavaScript will be converted to an ISO-8601 date-formatted String (because JSON can't serialize it directly as a Date), so you can pass that object to a `Date`, `DateTime`, or `String` parameter, and it'll work just fine.

Similarly, you can use `true` or `"true"` to get a Boolean true value in Apex, but note that *any* value other than these two will result in the value `false`, except `null`, which will transform to `null`. Even `"True"` will be false when it gets to Apex, so be aware of case-sensitivity here.

From a practical perspective, you should try to always use the correct data type whenever possible by using the appropriate data type. Prefer strings for string parameters, Number types for the various Apex number types, and so on. If you're not sure, try using the parameter's data type `.valueOf` method, and see what you get back. If you get the value you expect, it should be safe to duplicate that value in Apex.

As long as you "try to do the Right Thing", Apex will probably work the way you expect it to. Because of the limitations of JSON, Apex has to be quite flexible in order to provide the best developer experience. However, don't expect it to be able to do things like converting a Date to any kind of Number directly. For example:

```
@wire(method, { theTime: new Date() }) value;
```

...

```
@AuraEnabled public static void method(Long theTime) {
```

This won't work, because a date string isn't a valid operation for `Long.valueOf()`. Instead, you could use one of the few methods to get the desired value:

```
@wire(method, { theTime: new Date().getTime() }) value;
```

Which would give you the epoch time from Jan 1, 1970 at midnight in milliseconds.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you. They key for me is that the syntax `'$'` is not doing string interpolation and that standard JSON serialization is being used for bridging the Javascript objects to Apex types. It's a little unsettling that some Javascript types might be coerced to other types when possible. I assume there's no "strict mode" of sorts that can be used to force all parameter values in JS to match those in Apex based on the parameter name?

Comment: @kennyc Correct. LWR is not given the method name, parameter types, return data type, etc, so a strict mode isn't possible. It would be possible for a dev to build a toolchain where the LWC is written in TypeScript, with language information on the Apex code  (Apex Language Server), and ensure data type coercion during build-time, and then cross-compiled valid LWR-compatible ES6 modules before deploying... but that's not a default build, so it might take some effort to figure it out.

Comment: In the serialized JSON `params`, does the name of each `key` have to match the name of the argument used in the Apex function signature? If so, how does that mapping happen if Apex doesn't support named parameters? If the serialized `key` does have to match, then I guess changing the parameter name in an Apex class could inadvertently break some LWCs.

Comment: @kennyc the keys must match the case-sensitive parameter names. Keys that do not map to a parameter are ignored, and parameters that do not receive a value will be null. The parameters are always named, as an object is sent (e.g. `{ "accountId": "001...", "contactId": "003..." }`). It is the developer's responsibility to make sure they match up correctly. It is an unfortunate design decision, but that's the state of affairs at the moment. Like I said, a dev could build a toolchain to detect this problem, but that's not OOTB.

Comment: Understood. Veering slightly off-topic, but if keys in JS need to map to parameter names in Apex, then the Apex compiler must preserve the parameter names somewhere, or generate some sort of mapping file, so that calling code knows what order to put the arguments in when invoking the Apex function. I *assume* an Apex function can't call another Apex function using a dictionary of key/value pairs that map to function arguments. This is only supported in whatever is performing the JS to Apex bridge....

Comment: @kennyc The client just serializes to JSON, and generates a payload that looks like: `{"actions":[{"id":"1;a","descriptor":"aura://ApexActionController/ACTION$execute","callingDescriptor":"UNKNOWN","params":{"namespace":"","classname":"MyClass","method":"myMethod","params":{"param1":"abc","param2":"xyz"},"cacheable":false,"isContinuation":false}}]}` and sends it to `mydomain.lightning.force.com/aura?r=X&aura.ApexAction.execute=1`. (where X is the request ID). It is `aura` that maps the parameters to Apex before it formally starts running.

Comment: @kennyc Apex is a strongly typed language, so you are correct, you cannot, in the general sense, pass key-value pairs to a method and expect it to run. It's for that reason we have `System.Callable`, an interface we can use to define a method `Object call(String method, Map<String, Object> params)` in an Apex class that allows this type of dynamic behavior.

Comment: Ah! `System.Callable` is indeed where the magic lies. So the serialized JSON gets deserialized and the `apexMethodParams ` are converted to an `Apex.Map`. `Aura` then calls into a class that implements `Callable.call(String, Map)` and that implementation calls the appropriate function. Only piece of the puzzle left is the class that implements `Callable`. This must be auto-generated based on `@ AuraEnabled` annotations because I would *assume* that argument names are lost during compilation to byte-code.

Comment: @kennyc It's not Apex itself. The Apex runtime is written in Java, and the compiler uses a type of bytecode. It's proprietary, but yes, the Java runtime can tell the data types and names of parameters, none of that is lost when calling Apex.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks so much for the insightful discussion.

Answer (score 0):

In LWC Salesforce, the `$` means that the value is passed dynamically. When the value changes, the wire service provisions data and the component rerenders.

**Making a Property as Dynamic and Reactive**

As per [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_wire_service_about)

> In the wire Method, when we prefix a value with `$` to reference a
> property of the component instance. The `$` prefix tells the wire
> service to treat it as a property of the class and evaluate it as
> `this.propertyName`. The property is reactive. If the property’s value
> changes, new data is provisioned and the component rerenders.
>
> We call the wire service reactive in part because it supports reactive
> variables, which are prefixed with `$`. If a reactive variable changes,
> the wire service provisions new data. We say “provisions” instead of
> “requests” or “fetches” because if the data exists in the client
> cache, a network request may not be involved.

We use the `$` prefix for top-level values in the configuration object. Nesting the `$` prefix such as in an array like `['$accountIds']` makes it a literal string, which is not dynamic or reactive.

In this example, `$recordId` is dynamic and reactive.

```
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

import REVENUE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.AnnualRevenue';

const fields = [REVENUE_FIELD];

export default class WireGetValue extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;

    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields })
    account;

    get revenue() {
        return getFieldValue(this.account.data, REVENUE_FIELD);
    }
}
```

A value without a `$`, like the value of the `fields` property in a above example, is a static value, `[AccountNameField]`.

You can designate these types of configuration object properties as dynamic and reactive.

So when you use `'$recordId'` in the `@wire` decorator, it is essentially a shorthand for `this.recordId`. The difference is that `$recordId` is reactive, meaning that if the value of `this.recordId` changes, the wire will be updated automatically.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but I don't think it addresses my question. The signature for `getRecord` is such that it does take strings as parameters, so string interpolation through `$recordId` makes sense. But a custom `Apex` function's signature might use other types. I would like to know how the parameters and their types in `apexMethodParams` are matched to arguments in the called `Apex` function.

Comment: @kennyc Correct. Honestly, as a perfectionist myself, I find it a bit annoying, but on the other side, the flexibility is nice to have--even I make the occasional mistake. Just try to keep your data types straight, Apex should do the heavy lifting for you.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation it states `apexMethodParams—An object with properties that match the parameters of the apexMethod` and according to my consideration if apex method expects a parameter that is not string  as but as  Integer named as `count` from our wire method we need to pass an Object as `{count:'$count'}` in apex also we need to define argument with same name as `Integer count`. `$` as in documentation is refers to a property of the component instance, also `$count` tells the wire service to treat it as a property of the class and evaluate it as `this.count` so `$count` would be evaluate to `this.count`. so in apex we have integer `count` and from wire we pass `{count:'$count'}` that evaluates to `{count=this.count}` . As document says  `apexMethodParams is an object to pass parameter values to an Apex method, pass an object whose properties match the parameters of the Apex method. For example, if the Apex method takes a string parameter, don’t pass a string directly. Instead, pass an object that contains a property whose value is a string.`

> To  @wire the component to the Apex method, the first parameter is a string, which is the name of the Apex method—in this case, findContacts. The second @wire parameter is an object that contains the parameters to pass to the Apex method. So, for example, even though findContacts takes a integer, we don’t pass a Integer as the second  @wire parameter. Instead, we pass an object that contains a property whose value is a integer: { count: '$count' }. (If the Apex method took another parameter, we would add another property to the object